# No Build Button on Visual Studio

Tags: build, visual-studio-2019, juce

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yGAlQ.jpg)

Hello, I have just downloaded JUCE and followed the simple tutorial on the JUCE website.
When I tried to run the jucer file that I made, I couldn't find how to build and run.
As shown on the image, there's no build button on the menu bar.
First, I thought that there was no build button because I haven't used the visual studio for about 6 months.
But when I looked others' window (through Youtube), there was  a build button on the menu bar.
Can anyone explain this to me and give me the solution??

Also, I have few more questions.

1. Other people could directly move to visual studio from JUCE by clicking the icon. However, my program just saves the process but not moving to visual studio. I'd like to know how make it work.
2. If the solution for my main question (not additional question written above) is due to file extension, (because it is jucer file), is there any method that I can run this jucer file??

Thank you.

Comment: You mean Visual Code?

Comment: I guess yes, visual studio code

Answer (score 0):

Visual studio code is more or less like text editor. I don't think so you can build **Projucer** project.

you can find this data in Projucer Manual.

> 1.2 System Requirements
>   The Projucer is available for all three major operating systems and has the following system requirements:

1. macOS : 10.9 or higher
2. **Windows : 8.1 or higher and Visual Studio 2015 or higher.**
3. Linux :  Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS

You can view more info in : [Source](https://juce.com/discover/stories/projucer-manual)